# Set JMenuBar position below JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, position, jmenubar

I am working with a JDialog that is setUndecorated(true) and has a JPanel included to replace the default title bar. Currently there is an internal frame inside the JDialog which has among other things a JMenuBar attached to it.

I would like to move the JMenuBar to the JDialog but have it displayed below the JPanel. How can I have a JMenuBar which is added to a JDialog appear below a JPanel which is added to the same JDialog.

Comment: *"I would like.."*  **I** would like to see a specific question.  Do you have one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your panel uses a BorderLayout. Then you can use:

```
panel.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.South);
```